# GIT For Windows - Failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Tags: proxy, git, ssl, visual-studio

There have been many questions asked on this subject but none of them have a definitive answer.

I am developing in Visual Studio 2017 (v15.8.5) on a company network, behind proxy with my Git repositories on Azure DevOps (formally VSTS).

When I try and do anything with the repo (Push/Pull/Sync etc) I am constantly getting errors `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`. The error occurs both when using the Team Explorer inside V/Studio or Git commands in a CMD (Administrator) window.

To resolve that problem, most answers where to use Git Credential Manager For Windows, within Got For Windows, so I have now v2.19.1

Now I am getting `Failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed`

If I disconnect from the company LAN and connect to an open WiFi (home, 4G) then everything works absolutely fine, so it is obviously something to do with how Git and my company proxy are communicating with each other.

This is the my global `.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = xxxxxxxxx
    email = xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxxx
[http]
    sslcapath = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/ssl/certs
    sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    sslBackend = schannel
```

If I had hair, I'd pull it out ... Please someone help..

Comment: Your paths are looking strange as they use different formats. Did you try to fix them?

Comment: I've changed the path for `sslcapath` to match sslCAInfo but still get `Failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed`

Comment: Are you still getting the other error? Did you try to manually check what certificate you're seeing if you check the azure URL? What kinds of certs did you put in the CA bundle? Does your company MITM SSL connections to scan them etc.?

Comment: Yes.. error still happens ... The CA bundle is what is provided by Git For Windows download... Everything else you said ... I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

set `http.schannelcheckrevoke=false` (requires git >= 2.19, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090169/3813064)

Please note that schannel uses the "Native Windows Secure Channel library" (in which your IT department also stores your company SSL certificates) and not OpenSSL. Therefore setting `sslCAInfo` will have no effect AFAIk.

Related Question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472724/why-schannel-fails-to-receive-handshake-from-the-server

In general: Make sure the `http.proxy` settings are set correctly. Have you tested them?

Try to clone something with behind the proxy using `http.sslVerify=False` to rule out that the proxy has a problem.

Note also that VisualStudio uses it's own implemted Git binary. So test first with the command line and make sure that the correct git binary is used (`where git` and `git --version`)

Comment: If you -1 it would be nice to leave a command to describe why...